# Groupby array of unique values with lodash

Tags: javascript

I have an array of ids, I want to have an array of arrays each containing their unique values, for example if I have an array like this:

```
const arrayOfIds = [1,2,2,4,2,4,5,5];
```

I want  to get a resulting array like the following:

```
[
    [1],
    [2,2,2],
    [4,4],
    [5,5]
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's the 22 coming from?

Comment: Please explain what the result means

Comment: Where's the other 4 going?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const arrayOfIds = [ 1,2,2,4,2,4,5,5 ];
const output = Object.values(_.groupBy(arrayOfIds));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```